# onClick event fired before clicking in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to remove the li whenever user click the delete button. So I pass the index around but it got triggered before I click on it, I guess I'm doing it wrong for passing the value.

http://jsfiddle.net/axhpuepq

```
var App = React.createClass({
   getInitialState(){
     return {
       items:[1,2,3],
       isEdit: false
     }
   },
   renderEditForm(){
   return(
   <div>
   <input type="text" />
   <button onClick={this.saveHandler}>save</button>
   </div>
   )
   },
   ItemCtrl(index){
   return(
   <div className="itemCtrlWrap">
   <button onClick={this.editHandler}>Edit</button>
   <button onClick={this.dltHandler(index)}>Delete</button>
   </div>
   )
   },
   editHandler(){
   this.setState({isEdit:true})
   },
   saveHandler(){
    this.setState({isEdit:false})
   },
   dltHandler(index){
     console.log(index) //shall recieve index here upon click
   },
   renderItem(){
     return(
       this.state.items.map((item,i)=>
         <li key={i}> {this.state.isEdit ? this.renderEditForm() : item} {this.ItemCtrl(i)}</li>)
     )
   },
   render(){
      return(
        <ul>
          {this.renderItem()}
        </ul>
      )
   }
})

React.render(<App />, document.getElementById('container'));
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You're executing the function instead of just setting it, here:

```
onClick={this.dltHandler(index)}
```

If you want to pass some arguments bind them. Like:

```
onClick={this.dltHandler.bind(this, index)}
```

or use an arrow function:

```
onClick={() => this.dltHandler(index)}
```

If you notice, we're setting a function while declaring it to `onClick`. And this function is just executing `dltHandler`.

Answer (score 2):

When you define the `onClick` like this it is calling that function on instantiation. You need to use `bind` or define an anonymous function:

```
   <button onClick={this.dltHandler.bind(this, index)}>Delete</button>
```

or

```
   <button onClick={() => this.dltHandler(index)}>Delete</button>
```

Both of these pass a function to the `onClick` handler - but they do not execute until `onClick` is fired. Note that doing this will cause a new function to be generated on every render call. This can be expensive computationally if you are rendering very often.

If performance becomes an issue it is a better solution to refactor the button into a separate component that has a defined `dltHandler` function.