# Button is automatically clicked

Tags: reactjs

I have made a simple button in react app.

```js
<button onClick={console.log('clicked')}>Click</button>
```

The problem is that button is continuously click without clicked by me.

Comment: `onClick={() => console.log('clicked')}`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Correct use of arrow functions in React](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48699573/correct-use-of-arrow-functions-in-react)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [onClick event fired before clicking in react](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39874747/onclick-event-fired-before-clicking-in-react)

Comment: you didn’t bind the console, you’ve just called it. Just wrap the console with a callback function.

Answer (score 2):

```
<button onClick={() => console.log('clicked')}>Click</button>
```

is the solution. When you put paranthesis without using the arrow function, it will automatically execute without waiting for you to click the button

Answer (score 0):

`onClick` takes function as a parameter. Try this and it should work correctly:

```
<button onClick={ () => { console.log('clicked') } }>Click</button>
```